# C Warning: Statement with no effect for hashing string

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I am trying to hash a string and I got the code from my textbook.

Here's the code:

```c
int hash(char *str) {
  int i, sum;
  for (sum = 0; i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    sum += (int) str[i];
  return sum % MODVAL;
}
```

The code giving me the error is `str[i] != '\0';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C `for` loop syntax is composed of 3 expressions

```c
for (initialization; condition; increment)
```

In your code you have four expression in your `for` loop declaration. If you want multiple initialisations (*e.g.* initialize `sum` and `i` to zero), you can delimit them with a comma instead:

```c
for (sum = 0, i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Works wonderful, I actually enjoy a simple fix, lol...

Comment: @EricPostpischil fixed